# Zip lists of tuples

Tags: python, functional-programming, zip, unzip

I'm doing some stuff with data from files, and I have already zipped every column with its info, but now i want to combine info from other files (where i have zipped the info too) and i don't know how to unzip and get it together.

EDIT:
I have a couple of zip objects:

```
l1 = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')] # list(zippedl1)
l2 = [('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')] # list(zippedl1)
l3 = [('i', 'j'), ('k', 'm')] # list(zippedl1)
```

and i want to unzip like:

```
unzipped = [('a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'k'), ('b', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'm')]
```

I wouldn't like to transform the zipped structures to a list, just for memory reasons. I searched and i didn't find something that helps me. Hope you can help me please!.
[sorry about my bad english]

Comment: `zip` objects use _less_ memory than a `list`, as they are lazily evaluated. This is assuming that your "zip objects" really are `zip` objects, because they look like `list` literals to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to zip an unpacked [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
# Leaving these as zip objects as per your edit
l1 = zip(('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd'))
l2 = zip(('e', 'g'), ('f', 'h'))
l3 = zip(('i', 'k'), ('j', 'm'))

unzipped = [('a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'k'), ('b', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'm')]
```

You can simply do

```
from itertools import chain
result = list(zip(*chain(l1, l2, l3)))

# You can also skip list creation if all you need to do is iterate over result:
# for x in zip(chain(l1, l2, l3)):
#     print(x)

print(result)
print(result == unzipped)
```

This prints:

```
[('a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'k'), ('b', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'm')]
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the lists first:

```
>>> l1 = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
>>> l2 = [('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]
>>> l3 = [('i', 'j'), ('k', 'm')]
>>> zip(*(l1 + l2 + l3))
[('a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'k'), ('b', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'm')]
```

Comment: I miss something on the explanation, sorry :(. I have l1, l2 and l3 as zip objects and i wouldn't like to trasnform into list!